# How to create a folder on a server by passing credentials using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, impersonation

I am working on a ASP.NET application using C# that is trying to read some files from a website by logging in and then writing the files on local drive.

I have already passed network credentials to logon to the website by reading the default credentials using -

```
request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Now i want to store the files on a server directory that requires some credentials to access the location.

Code of logging on to the website -

```
                string webUrl = "https://web.site.com/";

            string formParams = string.Format("user={0}&password={1}", username, password);

            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(webUrl);
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
            req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
            {
                os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();

            cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];
```

And the location is `\\11.11.11.11\Folder\`

How can I pass credentials for accessing that location?
I have learned about `impersonation` but not getting anything helpful so far. I have credentials that gives access to the location. But how can I do so by using C# code?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you saying the ASP.NET application is reading files server-side after logging on, and then trying to save them to a folder local to the server? If so, the problem will be the permissions for the account under which the web server is running. By default it will not have access.

Comment: If the problem is as @Michael states, you should simply give the account that runs the app the right credentials. The solution in my answer below is way too complex in that case and does not apply to this problem.

Comment: no not local to that server but a different server on a different domain. when I try to access the location by typing the address of the server it asks for username and password. I need a way so that I can logon to that server from my application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`LogonUser`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.LogonUser) API for this. You use the `LogonUser` function to create a token that represents the `WindowsIdentity` you want to impersonate. You then create a `WindowsIdentity` using the token and call [`Impersonate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx) on the identity. All code that follows runs under the impersonated identity.

Make sure that you always [`Undo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.undo.aspx) the [`WindowsImpersonationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.aspx).

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern bool LogonUser(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, 
                                    string lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, 
                                    int dwLogonProvider, out IntPtr phToken);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public extern static bool DuplicateToken(
    IntPtr ExistingTokenHandle, int SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL,
    out IntPtr DuplicateTokenHandle);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hHandle);

const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
IntPtr hToken;
IntPtr hTokenDuplicate;

if (LogonUser(username, domain, password,
              LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out hToken))
{
    if (DuplicateToken(hToken, 2, out hTokenDuplicate))
    {
        WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(hTokenDuplicate);
        WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext =
            windowsIdentity.Impersonate();
        try
        {
            // Access files ...
            // ...
        }
        finally
        {
            impersonationContext.Undo();   
            if (hToken != IntPtr.Zero) CloseHandle(hToken);
            if (hTokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero) CloseHandle(hTokenDuplicate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can either use the approach I describe or you should run your application using credentials that have access to `\\11.11.11.11\Folder\`. AFAIK there are no other approaches.